# What are the additional capabilities of Eclipse Modeling Framework w.r.t traditional compiler development for a DSL?

Tags: oop, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-emf

I'd like to understand the supplemental capabilities of Eclipse Modeling Framework ([EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/)) with respect to traditional compiler development for a DSL.

I clearly understand that EMF development flow classically starts with the definition of metamodels (or reuse of standardized ones; like UML), but that does not seem to differ that much from the activity of AST definition (say in 00-languages) in the compiler folklore. That even add supplemental efforts because of heterogeneous technologies.

What I guess however is that metamodels may have generally more information than AST classes, because they appear as graph, and as such the EMF tooling can take advantage of these information for contextual checking. Is that the difference ? And is it worth the effort ?

I also understand that tools like Xtext may somehow fill the gap between the two communities.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract syntax tree is a pure data structure. In contrast to this, an EMF model consists of data represented by EClassifiers with their EAttributes and EReferences and behavior that is represented by EOperations.

> What I guess however is that metamodels may have generally more
>   information than AST classes

So yes, you are right. The bit more information an EMF meta model contains are the operations.

> is it worth the effort ?

That heavily depends on your use case. Defining behavior together with the data that it operates on is commonly considered good OO practice.

Comment: @JCLL I don't coun't getters and setters as behaviour even if they are methods. What other methods do they have?